# What is the frame size in result of collision in token ring?

Tags: network, topology

I have on my studies one exercise and I don't know how to solve it.
What is the size of frame in result of collsion in token ring, where length of link is L = 6km, number of stations n = 50 and speed of transmission is 25Mbps. There is aplied rival algorithm with access to link.
Could someone calculate it or simply explain?

Comment: All education, certification, or homework is explicitly off topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. By the way, the advantage of token bus and token ring is that they do not have collisions because only the station holding the token can transmit.

Answer (score 1):

Token ring uses (used) a token for arbitration/multiplexing - hence the name. There can be no collisions.